# Run an interactive script with administrator privileges, before user login

Tags: windows-7, boot, script, truecrypt

Windows 7.

I have a script which mount a TrueCrypt partition and share it across a LAN.
Because this script must run with administrator (at least power user) privileges, I place it in gpedit.msc -> Computer Config -> Startup Script.

I don't want to place the TrueCrypt volume password in script, so a gui interaction needed (a small TrueCrypt inputbox wants password).

On Windows XP, this TrueCrypt window appear on welcome screen.
On Windows 7, it is not appear at all (maybe in background? - script is run for sure)

So, the question is, how can make TrueCrypt login window appear in Windows 7 welcome screen?

Comment: afaik this is no longer possible, because XP used GINA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication) as logon system which was removed in Vista, so Win7 also misses GINA.

Comment: Is there a workaround for a user of 'Users', which know password of TrueCrypt volume, to mount it and share it? Commands are:
truecrypt /q /lz /v topsecret.tc
net share Z=z:\